Remote Xdebug and 504 on lost connection
I set up a remote Xdebug to work through the SSH tunnel. Everything works perfectly, but if I eventually drop the SSH connection (lost internet connection, switch VPNs or just close the laptop screen) my remote website drops into 504 error. Restarting nginx and php-fpm doesn't help. The website simply wakes up on its own after 15-20 min.
Seems that there is a kind of timeout somewhere? Can you help where? And what can I do to prevent the site dropping into 504?
php.ini:
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9093
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM

(yes, I use port 9093 for Xdebug and it works)
To create SSH tunnel I use putty:

=== update:
Got no ideas. The problem is still actual, so late replies are welcomed. Thanks

This looks like Putty inability to reconnect cleanly, have you tried mobaxterm with the auto reconnect feature on a tunneling if it corrects the problem and make sure it's not Putty fault ?
Also, if there is a failure without loss of connection, be sure to check the SSH configuration to define a keep alive.

Thx. Well it can be so. But the situation is: 'I closed my laptop and went home from office. And the guys starts to call me what's up with the dev site :) '. I'm looking for the server-side solution.
